# Split string using 2 different delimiters in Bash

Tags: regex, string, bash, split, ifs

I am trying to split a string in BASH based on 2 delimiters - Space and the \. This is the string:-

```
var_result="Pass results_ADV__001__FUNC__IND\ADV__001__FUNC__IND_08_06_14_10_04_34.tslog"
```

I want it to split in 3 parts as follows:-

```
part_1=Pass
part_2=results_ADV__001__FUNC__IND
part_3=ADV__001__FUNC__IND_08_06_14_10_04_34.tslog
```

I have tried using IFS and it splits the first one well. But the second split some how removes the "\" and sticks the entire part and I get the split as :-

```
test_res= Pass
log_file_info=results_ADV__001__FUNC__INDADV__001__FUNC__IND_08_06_14_10_04_34.tslog
```

The IFS I used is as follows:-

```
echo "$var_result"
IFS=' ' read -a array_1 <<< "$var_result"
echo "test_res=${array_1[0]}, log_file_info=${array_1[1]}"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to pass `-r` to `read` to tell it not to evaluate escapes.

Comment: @EtanReisner you were right in both the cases. I missed the use of -r. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
IFS=' |\\' read -ra array_1 <<< "$var_result"
```

Comment: Can someone please give answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556202/split-string-using-r-n-in-bash ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
#!/bin/bash
var_result="Pass results_ADV__001__FUNC__IND\ADV__001__FUNC__IND_08_06_14_10_04_34.tslog"
field1=$(echo "$var_result" | awk -F ' ' '{print $(NF-1)}');
field2=$(echo "$var_result" | awk -F  \\ '{print $(NF-1)}');
field1=$(echo "$field1" | awk -F ' ' '{print $(NF-1)}');
field3=$(echo "$var_result" | awk -F  \\ '{print $2}');
echo $field1;
echo $field2;
echo $field3;
```