# Split string using \r\n using IFS in bash

Tags: bash, ifs

I would like to split string contains \r\n in bash but carriage return and \n gives issue. Can anyone give me hint for different IFS? I tried IFS=' |\' too.

## input:

```
projects.google.tests.inbox.document_01\r\nprojects.google.tests.inbox.document_02\r\nprojects.google.tests.inbox.global_02
```

## Code:

```
IFS=$'\r'
inputData="projects.google.tests.inbox.document_01\r\nprojects.google.tests.inbox.document_02\r\nprojects.google.tests.inbox.global_02"
for line1 in ${inputData}; do
    line2=`echo "${line1}"`
    echo ${line2} //Expected one by one entry
done
```

## Expected:

```
projects.google.tests.inbox.document_01
projects.google.tests.inbox.document_02
projects.google.tests.inbox.global_02
```

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: BTW, in `string="foo\r\n"`, you don't actually have a literal CRLF sequence inside the variable (as it would be if you'd retrieved that variable's contents from a file, for example). To assign that sequence to a string, you need `string=$'foo\r\n'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following awk could help you in your question.

```
awk '{gsub(/\\r\\n/,RS)} 1'  Input_file
```

OR

```
echo "$var" | awk '{gsub(/\\r\\n/,RS)} 1'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
projects.google.tests.inbox.document_01
projects.google.tests.inbox.document_02
projects.google.tests.inbox.global_02
```

***Explanation:*** Using `awk`'s `gsub` utility which is used for globally substitution and it's method is `gsub(/regex_to_be_subsituted/,variable/new_value,current_line/variable)`, so here I am giving `\\r\\n`(point to be noted here I am escaping here `\\` which means it will take it as a literal character) with `RS`(record separator, whose default value is new line) in the current line. Then `1` means, `awk` works on method of condition and action, so by mentioning `1` I am making condition as TRUE and no action is given, so default action print of current will happen.

***EDIT:*** With a variable you could use as following.

```
var="projects.google.tests.inbox.document_01\r\nprojects.google.tests.inbox.document_02\r\nprojects.google.tests.inbox.global_02"
echo "$var" | awk '{gsub(/\\r\\n/,RS)} 1'
projects.google.tests.inbox.document_01
projects.google.tests.inbox.document_02
projects.google.tests.inbox.global_02
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you answer by taking string value instead of file?

Comment: @JiteshSojitra, please check my edited OR solution now and let me know if you have any queries on same. Explanation has been added too now.

Comment: It works, now i need to again take a loop to read each instead of had a way in above code using IFS?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, please don't encourage folks to `echo $var` (unquoted expansion).

Comment: @JiteshSojitra, no Jitesh, you need not to use awk in any loop. awk could read any file by itself. If you have some other requirement then kindly do let us know in a new post, if it is minor question then let us know here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Apologies somehow I missed it, it has been added now. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, yes its minor for e.g in question line2 variable shows each line value. This prints row output for all.

Comment: @JiteshSojitra, not sure if I get it, if you are using above awk solution is it required, kindly do let me know on same please.

Comment: Done. for line2 in $(echo "$var" | awk '{gsub(/\\r\\n/,RS)} 1'); do
      echo ${line2}
     done

Comment: @JiteshSojitra, in spite of doing it, you could do it with single awk itself, try it out once and could save it's output into a variable, no need for a for loop here.

Comment: @JiteshSojitra, ...also, `echo "$line2"` is better-behaved than `echo ${line2}`. If your line contains a `*`, for example, then the version without the quotes will emit a list of files in the current directory, whereas the version with the quotes will emit that `*`. (Curly braces make no difference to correctness in this context one way or the other, so I suggest leaving them out unless you're in a context where they're specifically helpful).

Answer (score 7):

```
inputData=$'projects.google.tests.inbox.document_01\r\nprojects.google.tests.inbox.document_02\r\nprojects.google.tests.inbox.global_02'
while IFS= read -r line; do
  line=${line%$'\r'}
  echo "$line"
done <<<"$inputData"
```

Note:

- The string is defined as `string=$'foo\r\n'`, not `string="foo\r\n"`. The latter does not put an actual CRLF sequence in your variable. See [ANSI C-like strings](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings) on the bash-hackers' wiki for a description of this syntax.
- `${line%$'\r'}` is a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) which strips a literal carriage return off the end of the contents of the variable `line`, should one exist.
- The practice for reading an input stream line-by-line (used here) is described in detail in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Unlike iterating with `for`, it does not attempt to expand your data as globs.

Comment: Interesting and thanks a lot! As value is coming from outside so i just need to replace with : inputData="${valueFromExternalSource}" ?

Comment: @JiteshSojitra, yup -- if the externally-provided value contains literals rather than escape sequences, that'll work perfectly.

Comment: @JiteshSojitra, ...by contrast, if the incoming string contains literal escape sequences, that raises a question of what that data *is*. If it's a JSON string, you're better off using `jq` to interpret it; if it has C-style printf escapes only, then you can use `printf '%b'` to convert them to literals, should that be your intent.