# Bash variable is causing disorder to the expected output

Tags: bash, variables, echo

I'm trying to create a JSON data and store it to a file and then feed it to the API call I'm gonna make. However, upon formatting the output of my echo command to make a JSON format a variable is causing disarray in the returned output. Below is my script

```
  cat "${SETTINGS_LIST}" | while read endpoint
  do
    echo "{\"id\": \"$n\", \"method\": GET, \"url\": \"$endpoint\"}"
    let n=n+1
  done
```

then this is the content of SETTING_LIST variable

```
/accounting-rules
/aging-buckets
/application-rules
/audit-trail-settings
/batch-aliases
/billing-cycle-types
/billing-list-price-bases
/billing-period-starts
/billing-periods
/billing-rules
```

And the output is returning like this:

```
"}id":"0","method":"GET","url":"/accounting-rules
"}id":"1","method":"GET","url":"/aging-buckets
"}id":"2","method":"GET","url":"/application-rules
"}id":"3","method":"GET","url":"/audit-trail-settings
"}id":"4","method":"GET","url":"/batch-aliases
"}id":"5","method":"GET","url":"/billing-cycle-types
"}id":"6","method":"GET","url":"/billing-list-price-bases
"}id":"7","method":"GET","url":"/billing-period-starts
"}id":"8","method":"GET","url":"/billing-periods
"}id":"9","method":"GET","url":"/billing-rules
```

When I removed the **endpoint** variable and change it to this, for example

```
echo "{\"id\": \"$n\", \"method\": GET, \"url\": \"/application-rules\"}"
```

I'm getting the expected output

```
{"id": "0", "method": GET, "url": "/application-rules"}
{"id": "1", "method": GET, "url": "/application-rules"}
{"id": "2", "method": GET, "url": "/application-rules"}
{"id": "3", "method": GET, "url": "/application-rules"}
{"id": "4", "method": GET, "url": "/application-rules"}
{"id": "5", "method": GET, "url": "/application-rules"}
{"id": "6", "method": GET, "url": "/application-rules"}
{"id": "7", "method": GET, "url": "/application-rules"}
{"id": "8", "method": GET, "url": "/application-rules"}
{"id": "9", "method": GET, "url": "/application-rules"}
```

Actions I have done:

1. Downgraded to older git bash version
2. Tried in my Ubuntu WSL but still getting the same error.
3. Tried different way of formatting the output to JSON by using JQ and printf command but issue still persist
4. The script works fine in different machine with same version of BASH and GIT BASH

Does anybody know the cause of this issue and how this could be possibly resolved?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to a little history lesson on how Unix and Windows thought differently about line endings!

On Unix (and Linux, Ubuntu, ...) a line ending is defined as a single `\n` character.

On Windows it’s a two-character sequence `\r\n`.

(For completeness, on old Macs it was a single `\r`, but that’s mostly irrelevant today.)

You’ve got a lovely, Windows-compatible text file, where lines are delimited with `\r\n`. Bash however, being a Unix tool, doesn’t handle `\r` specially and splits the lines only at the `\n` characters.

Therefore, every instance of your `$endpoint` variable contains a single `\r` at the end.

Now, `\r` is also called “Carriage Return”, from old typewriters, and that’s exactly what Bash’s output routine does, when it encounters a `\r`: jump back to the start of the current line and replace all characters with what follows after. That’s why you see such strange, garbled output.

Fix: Remove the `\r` before using the variable. E.g., the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46556457/113195) suggests a solution like this:

```
cat "${SETTINGS_LIST}" | while IFS= read -r endpoint
do
    endpoint="${endpoint%$'\r'}"
    echo "{\"id\": \"$n\", \"method\": GET, \"url\": \"$endpoint\"}"
    let n=n+1
done
```

Comment: You are a god disguised into human. I appreciate a lot your help plus the additional info you provided. This makes complete sense to me now.

Comment: Btw, what was the role of the IFS after the while command?

Comment: IFS is a bash-internal variable, the “Internal Field Separator” characters, https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSREF . Bash will use the characters in this variable to split entries. Setting it to an empty value means “don’t do anything unexpected, split only at `\n`”. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26784/understanding-ifs has nice examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your settings-list obviously has carriage return characters in it. Replace `cat "${SETTINGS_LIST}"` by `dos2unix < "${SETTINGS_LIST}"`, i.e.

```
dos2unix <"${SETTINGS_LIST}"` | while read endpoint
```

In case you don't have `dos2unix` yet (I don't remember whether it ships with the Mac), [install it from the Appstore](https://macappstore.org/dos2unix/).